# Kaa sandbox demo application running infinitely & data not storing in Mongo DB?

Tags: database, linux-kernel, kaa

So I was able to run the demo application as described in 
http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Your-first-Kaa-application/#sample-client-application

But the application would not stop running and I have to manually stop it. Also, whenever I check to see if the data has been stored in Mongo DB, nothing shows up.

If anyone had a similar issue I would love to know what I might be doing wrong.

Thnaks!